Whats the source of saying Al Cheit at night?
BH
Whats the source saying al chait every night at kiryat shma al hamita?

The Arizal in Pri Etz Chaim Shaar Krias Shema She'al Hamitah chapter 10:

צריך שיהיו נגד עיניו כל החטאים שבאו לידו אותו היום, ויהיה נגד עיניו בעת שכיבתו, ויתודה עליהם בפיו, אחר הק"ש כנודע, שסידורו הוא אחר יושב בסתר עליון, ואלין אקרון מארי דחושבנא בכל לילה. וצריך שלא לאבד שום אחד מהם, רק כל החטאים והדיקדוקים שעשה ביום ההוא, יתוודה עליהם בעת השכיבה, ולא ישכח אחד מהם:
He needs there to be, before his eyes, all of the sins that came to his hands that day, and that they be before his eyes at the time he lied down, and that he confess them with his mouth, after Krias Shema, as it is known, whose place is after Yoshev B'seiser Elyon - which we call the " master of evaluation" every night. He must not leave out any one of them - rather, all of the sins and particulars that he did during the day he must confess at the time of sleep, and not forget any of them.

